# How to reinitialize the cell in uitableview without duplicating value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on one application where i am fetching some data in uitableview and when i am scrolling that table,it duplicates value. I know that it happens because i am using reuse identifier to initialize the cell. But then what is the remedy to neglect this problem?I am using below code.What if i don't want to use reuse property?

```
CellForClient  *cell = (CellForClient *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CellForClient alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
```

Any solution?Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

@Erik B & RedBlueThing: Thanks for your reply but this is what i am already doing and getting duplicated value as i am using reuseIdentifier to initialize the the cell. Let me give u example: I am having 6 rows in my table.Each cell contains 7 inner values like first name,last name and some other details.So at the beginning i am showing 3 cells when i load the table.When i scroll table down and up again,the last rows' data overwrites the upper values and with each scroll,the values gets overwritten.

Any solution for my this problem.

Comment: try removing if(cell == nil)
 check. It will solve your problem but it is not a right approach. the right approach is to use a custom cell created by either using interface builder or by code. If you need further help let me know.

Comment: @rahul : I am creating the custom cell in different class using code itself.and calling the object here with above code.First time it scrolls well but if i scroll again up and down and select any cell,my app crashes.

Comment: Also tried to remove "if(cell == nil)",but in vain.instead my previous data becomes blank.

Comment: If you could post the full `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code, we could probably spot what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The important part of the code is where you set the data and you haven't included that.

Comment: @RahulVyas - That's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

If you look at the `// Configure the cell...` comment. That's where you should always set the data. If you don't, you might get a reused cell that used to be on another position and since you're not reseting it, it will still show the data for the old position.

Comment: Yep, the code to initialize the cell should be in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and should occur whether or not a cell is reused.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of cell reuse with your UITableView. Just make sure you are setting the textLabel.text property on the cell to the new value.

So the line after the if statement should be:

```
cell.textLabel.text = data for this row ...
```

You can test this is working by setting the text to something recognizable:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", indexPath.row];
```

So even if you are reusing cells, you will get "row 0", "row 1" etc ...

**Edit for update**

So you need to make sure that you are re-setting all the inner values after you get your cell object, either from the allocation or the *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier*.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this is what I did to fix it.
I created a custom class of type UITableViewCell and assigned it as the Custom class for that table cell in story board.
Then added a label in the cell and created a outlet for that label in the above custom class.

```
@interface SystemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *systemLbl;    
@end
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath used the above custom class instead of UITableViewCell

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    SystemCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell=[[SystemCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

//other code

UILabel *systemLbl = cell.systemLbl;
systemLbl.text = systemName;

return cell;
```

I use this in situations where I have to add a button for each row, this way I can identify the correct button. Otherwise it get duplicated when we scroll due to cell reuse.

Hope this help for anyone having a similar issue.

Comment: That is the only solution I found, when I have buttons in each cell. When I click a button, how do I identify which button was clicked? If I didn't use the custom class, when I scroll and click on a button, it 's tag shows a value which is same as one in the top of the table due to the table cell being reused. So what is the best way to handle that?

Comment: You can always set the tag value in the button, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes. That's what I do. But on the button click method, when I read the tag as int tag = [sender tag]; it return wrong values because it has reused the buttons. For e.g if there are 10 rows are displayed on the initial screen without scrolling, after I scroll and select the button on the second row, it'll return the tag as the tag of the button in the original second row before scrolling. Hope you can understand what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: If you set the tag to identify the cell index, *and do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath* (even when the cell is being reused), it will be correct.

Comment: When I set the tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath it sets, correctly. But the problem is when reading it in the button click method. This is how I set the tag, [joinBtn setTag:(100 + indexPath.row)];

Comment: And I'm guessing you only do that if you've created a new button.

Comment: This is what I tried initially inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    } <br> UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteSystem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:(1000 + indexPath.row)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];